# Remove unwanted symbols and caps from a field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have a classified site and need a little help from javascript experts.
When users post an ad in my site they tend to use ALL CAPS.
like : "HELLO THIS IS MY POST TITLE"
or some times special symbols like " * HELLO this is >>>>> a special ads special symbol || 999999 "

by using javascript how to make only the first letter of title in caps and rest in small and also exclude all special symbols after they post it (even with caps and symbols in the title)

Comment: You need to post your relevant code.  Basically any string has a `toLowerCase()` method that will lower case your text.  `Regex` can replace any unwanted characters

Comment: [You could use `CSS`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10256138/1064325)

Comment: sorry. I am a newbie. I have no idea about javascript. No need to discourage with a -1. Also @falsarella is it possible to remove special symbols with css?

Comment: @Keerthi sorry, I don't think so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you would want to do that in Javascript rather than server-side, but here's a possibility:

```
var text = $('#title').val().toLowerCase().replace(/[^\w\s]/g,"").replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g,"").replace(/\s+/g," ");
$('#title').val(text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.substr(1);
```

It only keeps letters and digits, makes sure there are no extra spaces, lowercases everything, uppercases the first letter.

Note that you may want to allow some special characters like " (for 32" for instance).

Comment: doing so on server side requires core modification of my cms.

Answer (score 1):

For starters:

```
function capitaliseFirstLetter(string)
{
    string.toLowerCase(); 
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

For the rest, just do a quick google search on how to clean a JS string.  Hint, you can write your own with a search/replace function.  Look up about RegEx functions too.

Answer (score 0):

To add on the above answer, use the replace function with regex. This should work:

```
string.replace([(\w|\d|\s]+, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = '567* hELLO         565 this is >>>>> a special ads special sy3mbol || 999999* fgdg'

str = str.toLowerCase().match(/[\w\d]+(?=[\W])|([\d\w]+)/g).join(' ')
str = str.replace(/\w/,function($1) {
    return $1.toUpperCase()
})
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qU9kP5)