# If the label text itself in the uppercase how to change a label text to the capitalize?

Tags: html, css

If the label text itself in the uppercase how to change a label text to the capitalize.

I tried this.

```
<p class="capitalize">THIS IS SOME TEXT.</p>
```

I have added

```
p.capitalize {
text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

I am getting the value as THIS IS SOME TEXT instead of This Is Some Text.
There are many ways of doing this by javascript but i want to achieve this only by CSS.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f3ureLts/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this.

[CSS text-transform capitalize on all caps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471157/css-text-transform-capitalize-on-all-caps)

As per link, you need to use either javascript or server side language like PHP

Comment: But i wanted like "This Is Some Text" is there any way in css

Comment: @SrinivasPai, No. There is no direct way using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to convert the text to lowercase serverside or using javascript for the css to take effect. You may want to have a look at the [MDN text-transform page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform).

Answer (score 0):

```css
p.capitalize {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<p class=capitalize>we love capitalizing things</p>
```

Options for capitalization variations are:
**none** | **capitalize** | **uppercase** | **lowercase** | **full-width**.