# Is here any method in HTML/CSS to transform both upper and lower letters to Capitalze?

Tags: html, css, text, transform

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp

From this link I have tried and it does transform text from lower case to Capitalize but it doesn't convert upper case into Capitalize.

For example, "HELLO" won't be converted into "Hello" using 'text-transform: capitalize;'.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not really, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471157/css-text-transform-capitalize-on-all-caps

Comment: `text-transform: capitalize` only uppercase the first letter of each word. Other letters are not changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this .. that should work!:

```
.link { text-transform: lowercase; }
.link:first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
```

(SRC: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10256138/7703846)

EDIT:

This isn't a clear solution, because there is no other way to fix ur problem via css, it will only uppercase the first letter for example... for a whole p / div element! If you want to use it on span you need to add display:block/display:inline-block too!
(thx to helb)

EDIT2: (Example)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>


p.capitalize {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
p.capitalize:first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p class="capitalize">THIS IS SOME TEXT.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That won't work for more than one word…

Comment: Its converting to small, but the first letter is not becoming capital.

Comment: @AntrikshaSomani `::first-letter` only works on block elements. So it should work with eg. `<p>` or `<div>` but not `<span>` etc. (unless you add `display: block` or `inline-block` to it).