# How to make first letter uppercase of full capitalized sentence using css

Tags: css, capitalize

I have a sentence like this 'MY FIRST LINE'. How to make first letter of each word capital letter and other letters small letters using css.

Comment: Looks like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471157/css-text-transform-capitalize-on-all-caps

Answer (score 0):

Using only css it is not possible. 
capitalize only affects the first letters of words. It will not change the case of the rest of the letters in a word. For example, if you capitalize a word that's in all capital letters already, the other letters in the word won't switch to lowercase. This is nice when your text includes an acronym or abbreviation that shouldn't include any lowercase letters.
For more detail follow this link: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-transform/